# How can I add draggable and droppable event listeners with jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile to build a mobile version of my site.

A lot of the features rely on drag/drop.

Since jQuery mobile uses Ajax to load the pages, the event handlers for draggable and droppable aren't added to elements on any page except the first.

How can I work around this without using in-line JS

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Is it possible to have an event listener for drag events on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

add references to your custom JavaScript files inside the page container div.